# Remove infinity wallpaper only from AOD

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-8

Just got my very first android today, being the S8 and am wondering how to remove any form of wallpaper from the AOD so its just black with the clock, but retain the wallpaper on the home screen.

Comment: Hi, by "AOD", did you mean "Always-On Display"?

Answer (score 0):

Use an external wallpaper app like Google's wallpaper app. Set the home and lock screen with a wallpaper. Then set the Infinity wallpaper you want, only for the home screen.
This worked for me.